Discrimination on the grounds of unsavoury religious beliefs?
Under UK law it's illegal for someone to discriminate against you because of your religion or beliefs.
What happens if those some of beliefs are currently socially unacceptable or illegal or immoral?
Consider the following scenarios...

Someone comes to a job interview and mentions that they believe that
homosexuals should be stoned to death and asks for assurances that
none of the other employees are gay.

A potential tenant views a property for rental. They mention that
they don't need any accommodation for their young daughters because
as soon as they reach 12 y.o. they'll be married off to a rich
relative on the other side of the world.

An employee is casually asked what they did over the weekend - they
say they went on training camp to learn how to slaughter unbelievers
when their priests tell them the time is right.


If the 1st one didn't get the job, the 2nd one didn't get the tenancy and the 3rd one got fired, could they claim they were discriminated against because of their beliefs?
For the purposes of this question let's assume that these are all sincere and deeply held beliefs in accordance with the basic tenets of their religion (rather than cultural practices). Lets also assume that the person who didn't give them the job (or tenancy) was honest (or foolish) enough to tell them that it was because of these beliefs that they didn't get accepted.
To be clear - this is intended as a hypothetical question, I'm not suggesting any religion actually expounds any of these doctrines. I'm interested in how the law deals with religious freedom when/if
those freedoms conflict with another religion or secular values. Hypothetical example - if one religion requires cats to be worshiped as Gods, and another believes cats are the agents of Satan and need to cleansed with fire then how does the law decide between the two?
I've not mentioned any particular religions in the question, so I don't think any need mentioning in the answers. Trying to keep this about question about the law only

Are you asking only about – for want of a better word – genuine religions, or are you including someone who holds abhorrent (to the interviewer etc.) views, but claims "that's what my [more-or-less invented on the spot] religion says"?

This reads like an attempt to goad and stir up argument. Downvoted.

@TripeHound The question already addresses that distinction, doesn't it?

Some ways of slaughtering animals (for consumption of believers) might be illegal in the UK. They are in Switzerland. While the practice is illegal, the belief is not, and is protected.

Surely the UK has an exception for bona fide job requirements, no? E.g. if I hire someone for a temporary job to drive people around on a Saturday, an Orthodox Jew cannot insist that I hire them despite the fact that they will not be able to perform any job duties. If that is the case, the first and third statements seem as if they could conflict with the job requirements even under accommodations: if I think that someone is preparing to slaughter unbelievers, that could conflict with their ability to do their job, as could refusing to work with any gay coworkers (or stoning them to death).

@MichaelHarvey The OP likely believes that these are legitimate reasons for discriminating against someone, and is looking to see what arguments there are for prohibiting such discrimination, but I don't see how that's worthy of a downvote.

Hmmm... what would be more interesting is less extreme examples. Stoning people to death, marrying off 12 year olds and slaughtering unbelievers is very obviously abhorrent and unlikely to land an employer in hot water if they refused to hire someone like that. But let's say the person mentioned their religion believed homosexuality was immoral and simply asked for the assurances, and the interviewer refused to hire them for that reason despite having no gay employees? Not sure if that's worthy of another question.

There are interesting questions to be had about beliefs whose validity tends to become a distraction to the general assertion of freedom of belief. "What if I went to camp to teach me to slaughter unbelievers" is not one of them. Either this question is intentionally manufactured to seek out extreme examples, or it is a genuine question based on a considerable lack of nuance that would be needed to understand the legal answer.

@Obie2.0: Whether explicitly enshrined or practically applied; most Western European nations consider discrimination based on actual performance of the job to not be discriminatory against a protected status, because the job is the main point of the application process. That Orthodox Jew's religion in your example is effectively irrelevant. If they don't work on the day the vacancy requires them to work, then that means they're a bad fit, regardless of why they won't work that day. Whether this is religious in nature, personal choice, or other responsibilities is irrelevant.

What constitutes a belief for the purpose of being a protected characteristic under Section 4 of the Equality Act 2010 was examined in Grainger plc v Nicholson [2010] IRLR 4.
There are 5 criteria which must be met which you can view at the above link. The relevant one for our purposes is:

It must be worthy of respect in a democratic society, be not
incompatible with human dignity and not conflict with the fundamental
rights of others.

Other case law has established that this is a high threshold i.e. it's only meant to exclude extreme cases. It's been said that it would exclude, for example, a belief in nazism. I suspect it would probably exclude your 3 examples too, but each case would be judged on its own facts.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answering strictly the question title: Beliefs enjoy wide protection; expressing them in language or even deed may infringe on the rights of others and is therefore more restricted. For example, "verbal abuse and harassment" are forbidden when they are "likely to cause violence, alarm or distress".
This tension is reflected in the wording in the European Convention on Human Rights which the UK ratified as the first country in the 1950s (emphasis by me):

ARTICLE 9
Freedom of thought, conscience and religion

Everyone has the right to freedom of thought, conscience
and religion; this right includes freedom to change his religion or
belief and freedom, either alone or in community with others and
in public or private, to manifest his religion or belief, in worship,
teaching, practice and observance.

Freedom to manifest one’s religion or beliefs shall be
subject only to such limitations as are prescribed by law and are
necessary in a democratic society in the interests of public safety,
for the protection of public order, health or morals, or for the
protection of the rights and freedoms of others.



In no way is religious freedom absolute or all-encompassing; in effect, the article states that its expression must be compatible with the society in which in is exercised. It is not even necessary that anybody be harmed; a violation of "morals" is sufficient.
It is up to the courts to find the equilibrium between the conflicting rights here, and given the wide latitude the law provides, that equilibrium must be found anew with each new generation.
To pick one of your examples: Child marriages, also in the UK,  have come into focus in recent years as societies worldwide grow more aware of sexual abuse and the sexual exploitation of power differentials in relations. There are campaigns aiming to close legal loopholes permitting the marriage of underage persons, typically girls.

The second set of belief would almost certainly (if freely expressed) result in the removal of said child due to their endangerment, and criminal charges.

@Richard That is an interesting question. The marriage will not be in the UK, outside its jurisdiction, and the parents surely have the right to travel "home" (are they British citizens? Would anything change if not?)  with their child. Would the authorities be allowed to take custody away from the parents if their plans become known? Would they be obliged? Also, international marriage right is interesting. Child marriages from abroad are not immediately invalid in Germany (not sure about the UK) because of alimony and inheritance implications; nor is a divorce abroad immediately valid.

Intending to travel to commit a crime is a crime in the UK. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/forced-marriage#understand-the-legislation-on-forced-marriage

@Richard Not everything that is forbidden is a crime... the husband, if of age, will commit statutory rape when the marriage is consummated, but he may not be British and may never go to Britain. Do the parents commit a crime?

Since they allowed (and apparently encouraged) this illegal marriage, then yes,.they would be guilty of a crime.
